# How to Update record values with values from an existing record in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL server 2012:

I need to do something similar here but I need to change values as follows:

There are 2 records for each M_id in mytable, differentiated by MAS. Where ever a value of "1" occurs in any of the value(1-80) fields on MAS=1 record, I need the values in record MAS=2 to be updated to match:

Before:

```
id |  M_id | MAS | value1 | value2 | value3.....up to value80
---|-------|-----|--------|--------|-------|
 1 |  100  |  1  |   0    |    1   |   0
 2 |  100  |  2  |   0    |    0   |   0
```

AFTER:

```
id |  M_id | MAS | value1 | value2 | value3.....up to value80
---|-------|-----|--------|--------|-------|
 1 |  100  |  1  |   0    |    1   |   0
 2 |  100  |  2  |   0    |    1   |   0
```

I need to do this to over 3000 records that I have the M_id's for in a list.

This is getting a bit to complicated for me to figure out, anybody know how to do this?

Thanks much,

MP

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: So sorry, I'm using SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 80 columns it is easier to use dynamic SQL instead of writing the whole Update query.

```
DECLARE @strQuery Varchar(MAX)

SET @strQuery = 'UPDATE T1 SET '

SELECT @strQuery = @strQuery + 'T1.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = T2.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' ,'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME Like 'Value%'

SET @strQuery = SUBSTRING(@strQuery,1,LEN(@strQuery) - 1) + ' FROM MyTable T1 INNER JOIN MyTable T2
                ON T1.m_id = T2.m_id
                WHERE T1.mas = 2
                AND T2.mas= 1
                AND T1.m_id IN(100,200,300,400,500)   '

-- IN Clause added after on the OP demand

--If you want to show up your Query
SELECT(@strQuery)
-- To execute it
EXEC(@strQuery)
```

*Note: i this will only update record where m_id = 100 or 200 or 300 or 400 or 500*

If you do not have a problem writing the whole query @MikeS answer will work well for you.

Comment: Ok, so if I see this correctly this is "finding and replacing" values = 1 for values 1-80 in MAS=2 that occurs in MAS=1 for M_ids that are equal, and it is cycling through ALL M_id's.  How would I get it to do this for only a select group of M_id's that I have in an excel list?  Lastly, other than mytable, what references must i change with my tables?  (aka, do the T1 and T2 references need to be changed)  Sorry, my Sql knowledge is limited.

Comment: T1 & T2 are aliases and they are used to make a join with the table it self (so mytable T1 will be considered a different table from myTable T2). if you have a list of Mid's you have to add a condition in `Where Clause`. i will edit my answer for that

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So if I want to test this on my table for just M_id=100, then I would use "AND T1.m_id IN(100)".  Between this and Mikes i hope to soon have my solution!  Thank you!

Comment: Oh crud, my Value fields are data type "BIT".   do I have to change this?    DECLARE strQuery Varchar(MAX) to DECLARE strQuery BIT(MAX)  ???

Comment: no!! @stQuery is a variable that store the query you have to execute. Try using SELECT (@strQuery) instead of EXEC(@strQuery) and it will show the query you have build

Comment: @mrpush when your question is solved don't forget to [accept the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I'm just about at a solution, Thanks Hadi for the help I really appreciate it!

Comment: U r welcome. I you found your own answer add it. So other user can read it

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
 update mytable_mas2
    set value1 = mytable_mas1.value1,
    value2 = mytable_mas1.value2,...

    from mytable mytable_mas2
            join mytable mytable_mas1
               on mytable_mas2.m_id = mytable_mas1.m_id
    where mytable_mas2.mas = 2
    and mytable_mas1.mas= 1
    and mytable_mas1.m_id in (200,201, ...)
```

If you only want specific m_id's affected, add in and m1.m_id in (the list of ids).

Comment: No so sure i understand the "Join mytable m2"....i don't have my ID's for the 3000 as another table, its just a list.

Comment: Next I see this updates Value M1 with M2, but that's not what I want, I want the 2nd record (MAS=2) to be update with the values in the MAS=1 record?  Sorry, I'm confused by this.  Are M1 and M2 temp tables?

Comment: I'm joining the table to itself based on m_id. m1 is the alias for the row with mas = 2 and m2 is the alias for the row with m1. (A bit confusing I know). They aren't temp tables, just a table joined back to itself.

Comment: I'll edit my post to make the aliases make more sense. As for the list of ids, how is this stored? You can't just pass a list into Sql Server.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  This is just a tab bit out of my current SQL comprehension.  I just have a list of the ID in excel....can I not just add them to the query and call then somehow in a cyclic fasion?

Comment: Mike, the edits are helping, thanks.  Can you show me how I would have this only make the changes on my list of M-id's please?  Like where would "M_id = 200" be added make the change on that ID as well?

Comment: How is the list stored? I will edit my sql to show how to do it if you have a comma delimited list.

Comment: I'm just about at a solution, Thanks Mike for the help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from a design error: an "array" of columns.  Now you want to search that array, and find no good way to do it because you're not using SQL as intended.

Numbered columns are almost always an example of keeping data in the metadata.  If we move that data back into the table, the SQL becomes easy.

Suppose you had a `value` column, and an `ordinal` column to say which one it is:

```
create table T( id int, M_id int, MAS int, 
                ordinal int not NULL check (ordinal between 1 and 80), 
                value int );

update T
set value = (
    select value from T as T2
    where T.id = T2.id and T.M_id = T2.M_id and T.ordinal = T2.ordinal 
    and MAS = 1
    )
where MAS = 2
and exists (
    select 1 from T as T2
    where T.id = T2.id and T.M_id = T2.M_id and T.ordinal = T2.ordinal 
    and MAS = 1
)
```

That's a single update statement.  It uses ANSI standard syntax to avoid anomalies that the proprietary T-SQL `update from` construct can lead to.

Among other advantages, you no longer have to store zeros.  You can treat missing values -- rows not present -- as implied zeros.  That would make your update a bit more complicated; thankfully SQL Server supports `merge`.

If you want to view your table in the way you've designed it, you wouldn't be the first.  Write a view to render it that way; it's commonly called *table-folding*.

Comment: I'm just about at a solution, Thanks James for the help I really appreciate it!